# Change Sitecore user from virtual to regular

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I created some virtual users from already existing Sitecore users, and used them for impersonation purpose.

Now I have a problem. Apparently the initial users are recognized now as virtual users.

What could I do to change them back to regular users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not Virtual, You can serialize the user and compair with a regular user. In the User Manager, click on Serialize User the file is written in the Serialization folder usually in the Data folder.

There are 2 user profiles in Sitecore: User or Visitor Profile.
In the User Mangager Edit the user, go to the Profile tab and Click on Change

There are multiple domains in Sitecore, check also the domain and the rols.

Comment: Yes, that one I know. But what I meant is that I need to change from code the fact that after impersonation, the previously impersonated users are detected as Virtual Users.

Comment: What I did notice, is that if I delete my browser's data (cache, cookies), the `isVirtual` method returns false now. Would this be related to some cookie set up in the process?

Comment: Could anyone please help me on this? It's really urgent.

Comment: Can you share the virtual user create code, maybe it helps

Comment: Well, as I mentioned above, it seems that is not related to Virtual Users. It has something with the information kept at runtime, which is recognized after I log out and log in again. If I delete session cookies manually, it works fine. But it doesn't work deleting them from code...they reappear after log in